# convert.exe: "missing an image filename" error

Tags: python, imagemagick, alpha

I'm invoking ImageMagick's convert.exe with the following python command:

```
os.system("convert -compress group4 %s -type bilevel -monochrome %s -alpha off" % (imagefilename,imagefilename.replace(ext1,ext2)))
```

Prior to adding "-alpha off" there were no errors, but the output image showed up as black and bright green instead of black and white.  After adding it, the output images display correctly, but every time an image is converted an error is output:

> .tifconvert.exe: missing an image filename `off' @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3065

Is there a way to suppress this error, since it slows down run time and makes a mess in the command prompt window?  I tried moving the -alpha off tag to before the file name, but then the images show up as green again in the image viewer.

Comment: Use the `call()` function in the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead of `os.system()` and redirect `stdout` and/or `stderr` to [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=devnull#os.devnull).

Comment: From the ImageMagick [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#alpha) it looks like you should be using `-alpha Off`.

Comment: Add a space after `-alpha off`.

Comment: Even with `-alpha off` there is an error message. I am using PHP on Ubuntu. Error: `convert-im6.q16: missing an image filename /srv/tmp/phpuNz7N2_preview.jpg @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3255.` - Anyone has another idea?

Comment: Update: The solution was to remove `-write` from the convert command. Now it works.